# Queueing of requiests to update data on client or server side?

Tags: http, post, model-view-controller, client-side, server-side

So I have a grid with sortable columns. On each sorting, there is an action like UpdataGridSorting that sends to the server POST request with the new data.

On the server, there is a method that updates data in a database. It does that in a pretty bad way: no locks to prevent simultaneous data updates in the db, only lock is for read while updating.

Therefore I have an issue: when user clicks several times on sorting, several requests get sent, they could overwrite data simultaneously and create dirty data.

So my workaround is to queue requests on some side and do not update database before previous update finished. On which side it's better to create queue?

Right now my intention is:

```
saveGridColumnSorting = (dataToSend, action, forceSend) ->
    if not forceSend
        queue.enqueue(dataToSend.id);
    if queue.lenght > 1 and not forceSend
        return
    $.ajax(
            url: url + "/" + action,
            data: dataToSend,
            success: (data) ->
                if (queue.lenght > 0)
                    saveGridColumnSorting(queue.dequeue());
        )
    return
```

Also, if you can see the XY problem, please refer to a pattern or any trustable source that will help to fix X in your answer.

Comment: What kind of sorting is it? Of a public resource, like a global phone book? Or just for dynamic per-user display purposes?

Comment: @YamMarcovic, What difference my answer makes? It's a per-user data in a public grid. Do you want to know amount of transferred data or time that will be spend on update in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the scheme with a queue on the client side proved that it works in action. However, an alternative was found: to block UI in time when user performs some action. Not a good experience for columns sorting, but still safer than queuing requests. Queuing on the server side would cause complexity to increase, especially for MVC application.

Answer (score 0):

Especially if the system is intended for more than one user (like you said in the comments), then there are obvious risks in doing this client-side. For starters, it's a security vulnerability. Secondly, what happens when you get more than one user issuing those calls?

So it should definitely happen on the server. At the same time, perhaps it's not the wisest choice to use a queue for such a task, since by doing this, one user could easily create a denial-of-service for others, by filling up the queue, or even causing the whole thing to crash from lack of memory.

There's also the question of what happens when user A requests to sort it one way, and then, before the database is re-read, user B has submitted their own sort request, which was already processed. Will not the first user get the wrong output, possibly without their being aware of it?

To avoid all of these issues—and provided that it's possible in terms of memory, and other information possibly not provided—you might choose to keep a cached copy of the result-set, which you would sort per-request, instead of modifying the actual database. Alternatively, if the database engine can do the sorting itself in a read-only way, then that's what should be used.

Comment: By “public grid” I had in mind that this grid is on every user's page, not that every user shares the one grid. There are different data for different users and, of course, sorting settings are stored in different records so that user can broke only his settings.